# Actions > Create User Record: created a new user account no email has been sent, why?

Tags: drupal, contacts, user-account

We'd like to automate user account workflow a bit and send a standard Drupal Welcome email each time new User Record created from within a Contact Action drop down in CiviCRM.

Currently we've got only "created a new user account for USERNAME,  no email has been sent" message.

It seems pretty logical to send emails at each new Drupal Account creation "by default", especially if all corresponded check boxes at /admin/config/people/accounts are checked.

What are we missing? Any clue, please!

Drupal 7.50, CiviCRM 4.6.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe any work has been done to enable this so a patch to core would be required.

The workaround we have often used is described in this [blog](https://civicrm.org/blog/petednz/creating-drupal-users-made-easy-for-single-or-multiple-contacts-via-civi-imports-and) - basically it uses a civi tag, that triggers a drupal rule, which then uses drupal default processes for creating a drupal user and hence sends out the email etc.

We developed that approach for different scenarios and is probably overkill but it works so we use it ;-)

Comment: Brilliant! Can't thank you enough! On a side note: have you seen any started attempts to make it works "out - of - box", mean core patch or any related php code?

Comment: nope - there have been discussions that civi 'should' be using the 'drupal way' for creating users but can't find those threads nor in jira. would be great if you can contribute this

Comment: Wish I knew where to start from, since Rules workaround has a little glitch: it is not reversible, mean, mirroring all rule conditions in order to delete user account by tag deletion, doesn't seem to work very well..

Comment: I don't follow. This ticket was about 'create a user account and send an email'. It had nothing to do with deleting user accounts.

Comment: I see; it's just about a possible logical reverse of workaround you've created. Simple put: if you create Drupal user account by tagging Civicrm contact, you may eventually want to delete this Drupal user by "un-tagging" the same Civicrm contact. Haven't been sure it worth a separate question created so decided to continue in comments, sorry.

Comment: I can't comment on whether Rules can be used to delete drupal user if you remove a Tag but it sounds like something that Rules should be able to handle. May be export your Rule and attach here, or better to new topic, and someone may help.